# "OpenURI::HTTPError: 401 Unauthorized" with Rails, HTTParty, and Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, httparty, eventbrite

I'm using HTTParty to get data from the Eventbrite API.

```
response = HTTParty.get("https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search?token=#{Figaro.env.eventbrite_oauth_token}")
```

I am trying to save an Event attachment to my object. (I'm using paperclip to upload images).

```
@event.image = "https://img.evbuc.com/http%3A%2F%2Fcdn.evbuc.com%2Fimages%2F18699100%2F162201087004%2F1%2Foriginal.jpg?h=200&w=450&rect=0%2C194%2C2000%2C1000&s=67649c6c8e7ef66e409189bf08474203"
```

But I get the error:

> "OpenURI::HTTPError: 401 Unauthorized" with Rails, HTTParty, and
>   Paperclip."

Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: Did you check if the value for `#{Figaro.env.eventbrite_oauth_token}` is a valid token?

Comment: Yes it's valid.

Comment: I was able to call `response = HTTParty.get("https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search?token=#{Figaro.env.eventbrite_oauth_token}") ` with my own token without any issue. Are you getting error at this call or later?

Comment: I only get the error when I try to save the image to my object @object.image . So the issue has something to do with Paperclip trying to Download/Upload the image from Eventbrite

Comment: What happens if you wrap the image URL string with `URI.parse()`?

Comment: that  fixed it! ^ thanks @ChrisPeters - want to leave an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've noticed in newer versions of Paperclip, I've needed to wrap any URL strings in `URI.parse` when asking Paperclip to import the asset via URL.

So for your example:

```
@event.image = URI.parse("https://img.evbuc.com/http%3A%2F%2Fcdn.evbuc.com%2Fimages%2F18699100%2F162201087004%2F1%2Foriginal.jpg?h=200&w=450&rect=0%2C194%2C2000%2C1000&s=67649c6c8e7ef66e409189bf08474203")
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked into Paperclip code to see why wrapping the URL in URI.parse works.

As it turns out, Paperclip uses different adapter classes to handle different targets.

The reason your attachment failed in the first place is because of [a recent change](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/commit/dfd73b3e6ba2bc4eb5f58b9c7812d388763e6d01) in URL handling in HttpUrlProxyAdapter which handles URLs.
This change is preventing from attaching files that have URLs that are already encoded.

Wrapping the URL with URI.parse made sure that your attachment was handled by URI Adapter.